# DNS-Settings on Network-Manager when using VPN

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn, vpnc

I recently updated to 19.04 and noticed some change in NetworkManager when using VPNs.

- I want to use a VPN with an own local DNS-server, which is pushed from DHCP
- I have seperate VPN profiles. One for a "full VPN" which installes a default-route to the remote network, and one "split tunnel" profile, having the setting for local resources only enabled

Since i updated to 19.04, NetworkManager seems to only use the pushed DNS server, what means when the default-route is allowed to install (when checkbox "use this connection only for resources on its network") is not checked.

Let NetworkManager install a default route:

```
~$ resolvectl status tun0
Link 16 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
          DNS Domain: local.domain
```

activate checkbox for local resources only in the same vpn profile:

```
~$ resolvectl status tun0
Link 8 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

This setting was working independently from default-route-setting before, seems like it changed with new 19.04 NetworkManager (v1.16.0). Can anyone confirm?

Edit: This is a **desktop** installation. Here are some details:

```
~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 20 15:41 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search uman.enbw.net

~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Are you using a **desktop** or **server** installation? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you find any resolution?

Comment: no still same situation here, i have not found a solution for this. still not using DNS when having no default routing...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I googled here and have exactly the same issue too. (Ubuntu 19.04)

For me, [this answer](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6076#issuecomment-543170324) solved.

```
nmcli c modify <vpn-settings-name> ipv4.dns-search '<domain>'
```

You should specify `<vpn-settings-name>` that corresponds to a VPN setting name in GUI.
And `<domain>` is the domain name you want to search via DNS in the remote network.

After reconnecting to VPN, `systemd-resolved status ppp0` shows

```
Link 6 (ppp0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1 (<--- my dns)
                      192.168.1.10
          DNS Domain: corp
```

Comment: at first try your command seems to do the trick here, too! I will observe this a few days and see if this command will be persistent.

Comment: after using the nmcli command for a few weeks i can confirm that this works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank  you, I've been trying to work out how to do this all week.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. And the cause is: Since Ubuntu19 we are using systemd-resolved, while NetworkManager still does the VPN Connection (which also did dns in older Ubuntu version)
The solution is: switch back to NetworkManagers builtin dns (or dhclient):

edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
add `dns=default` (or `dns=dhclient`) into the `[main]`-section.
then:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: In `Ubuntu 22.04` it works. thanks a lot!

Comment: worked with 22.04.3 jammy with bridged vpn setup

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to [soymsk's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183690). It seems that the DNS server from the VPN connection will be used if either:

- The VPN is set to be used for all traffic
- There is a DNS Search Domain associated with the VPN connection

As soymsk suggested, you can set the search domain on the client using `nmcli`.

If you're in control of the VPN server it's probably better to push out the DNS Search Domain from the VPN server. That way you don't have to set it on each client.

I added the following line to `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` on my VPN server and it had the same effect as setting the DNS Search Domain on the client:

```
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN <domain>"
```

Where `<domain>` is the domain you want added to any unqualified host names you try to access (the domain of your local network).
 the important thing seems to be that a DNS Search Domain is set for the VPN connection, it doesn't matter how the DNS Search Domain is se